# phonegap android native function not getting called

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins, native-code

my html code in /assets/www

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<\html>

<\head>

<\title>FileReader Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

function onLoad() {
    console.log("in onLoad");
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    execute(success, fail, "Echo", action, [args,"1","2"]);
    console.log("in at end of onLoad");
}


function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("in onDeviceReady");
}


function success(file){
    console.log("success");
}

function fail(evt) {
    console.log("in fail");
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}

<\/script>
<\/head>

<\body onload="onLoad()" >

<\h1>Example</h1>

<\p>Read File</p>

<\/body>

<\/html>
```

My java class code

```
package com.example.testphonegap;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.util.Log;

public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin {
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext)     throws JSONException {
    // if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("echo")) {
    String message = args.getString(0);
    this.echo(message, callbackContext);
    Log.v("success", "success");
    return true;
    // }
    // return false;
}

private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
        callbackContext.success(message);
    } else {
        callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
    }
}
}
```

line added in config.xml in /res/xml

```
 <plugin name="Echo" value="com.example.testphonegap.Echo" />
```

My Logcat

```
04-15 12:22:38.455: I/dalvikvm(778): Could not find method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.setOverScrollMode, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.init
04-15 12:22:38.455: W/dalvikvm(778): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1098: Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView;.setOverScrollMode (I)V
04-15 12:22:38.455: D/dalvikvm(778): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0043
04-15 12:22:38.615: I/CordovaLog(778): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
04-15 12:22:38.635: I/CordovaLog(778): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
04-15 12:22:38.655: D/CordovaLog(778): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=true
04-15 12:22:38.655: I/CordovaLog(778): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
04-15 12:22:38.665: D/CordovaLog(778): Found preference for exit-on-suspend=false
04-15 12:22:38.665: D/DroidGap(778): DroidGap.onCreate()
04-15 12:22:38.725: I/dalvikvm(778): Could not find method android.webkit.WebView.<init>, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<init>
04-15 12:22:38.725: W/dalvikvm(778): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 344: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
04-15 12:22:38.725: D/dalvikvm(778): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0001
04-15 12:22:38.745: D/dalvikvm(778): VFY: dead code 0x0004-0046 in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V
04-15 12:22:39.465: D/JsMessageQueue(778): Set native->JS mode to 2
04-15 12:22:39.475: I/CordovaWebView(778): Disabled addJavascriptInterface() bridge since Android version is old.
04-15 12:22:39.485: E/dalvikvm(778): Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.getWhitelistResponse
04-15 12:22:39.525: W/dalvikvm(778): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 129 (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;) in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;
04-15 12:22:39.525: D/dalvikvm(778): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000b
04-15 12:22:39.525: D/dalvikvm(778): VFY: dead code 0x000d-0014 in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;.getWhitelistResponse ()Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;
04-15 12:22:39.585: W/dalvikvm(778): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
04-15 12:22:39.615: W/dalvikvm(778): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
04-15 12:22:39.615: W/dalvikvm(778): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;)
04-15 12:22:39.665: D/DroidGap(778): DroidGap.init()
04-15 12:22:39.696: D/CordovaWebView(778): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/library_access.html)
04-15 12:22:39.725: D/PluginManager(778): init()
04-15 12:22:39.765: D/CordovaWebView(778): >>> loadUrlNow()
04-15 12:22:39.775: D/CordovaWebView(778): >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/file_reader.html)
04-15 12:22:39.775: D/PluginManager(778): init()
04-15 12:22:39.805: D/CordovaWebView(778): >>> loadUrlNow()
04-15 12:22:39.805: D/DroidGap(778): Resuming the App
04-15 12:22:39.915: D/DroidGap(778): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/library_access.html)
04-15 12:22:39.955: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(778): Ignore this event
04-15 12:22:40.084: D/Cordova(778): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/library_access.html)
04-15 12:22:40.084: D/Cordova(778): Trying to fire onNativeReady
04-15 12:22:40.095: D/DroidGap(778): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
04-15 12:22:40.095: D/DroidGap(778): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/library_access.html)
04-15 12:22:40.134: D/DroidGap(778): onMessage(onPageStarted,file:///android_asset/www/file_reader.html)
04-15 12:22:40.225: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(778): Ignore this event
04-15 12:22:41.184: D/dalvikvm(778): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 2668 objects / 187648 bytes in 208ms
04-15 12:22:42.185: D/DroidGap(778): onMessage(spinner,stop)
04-15 12:22:44.655: D/CordovaLog(778): in onLoad
04-15 12:22:44.655: I/Web Console(778): in onLoad at file:///android_asset/www/file_reader.html:10
04-15 12:22:44.695: D/CordovaLog(778): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: execute
04-15 12:22:44.695: E/Web Console(778): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: execute at file:///android_asset/www/file_reader.html:12
04-15 12:22:47.615: D/CordovaLog(778): Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only.
04-15 12:22:47.615: I/Web Console(778): Falling back on PROMPT mode since _cordovaNative is missing. Expected for Android 3.2 and lower only. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.6.0.js:906
04-15 12:22:47.935: D/CordovaNetworkManager(778): Connection Type: 3g
04-15 12:22:47.985: D/CordovaNetworkManager(778): Connection Type: 3g
04-15 12:22:47.995: D/DroidGap(778): onMessage(networkconnection,3g)
04-15 12:22:48.096: D/DroidGap(778): onMessage(spinner,stop)
04-15 12:22:48.134: D/Cordova(778): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/file_reader.html)
04-15 12:22:48.134: D/Cordova(778): Trying to fire onNativeReady
04-15 12:22:48.145: D/DroidGap(778): onMessage(onNativeReady,null)
04-15 12:22:48.145: D/DroidGap(778): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/file_reader.html)
04-15 12:22:48.335: D/CordovaLog(778): in onDeviceReady
04-15 12:22:48.335: I/Web Console(778): in onDeviceReady at file:///android_asset/www/file_reader.html:18
```

Comment: When does your onload function got called?

Comment: @wmfairuz please see my updated question, you will know. I have added extra \ before every tag in html code, because it wasn't printing my code as it is. I think there should be some way to avoid this, because for guys like me, who don't know html, it becomes very hard to avoid it

Comment: I've never seen those dalvikvm error messages before, it makes me think maybe something is wrong in your configuration? Did you set the target API level to the latest android? Also, this line: ``ReferenceError: Can't find variable: execute at file:///android_asset/www/file_reader.html:12`` makes me think that in your JavaScript you should be calling  ``cordova.execute`` or ``window.plugins.Echo()``? Have you created and can you paste the Echo.js file? Cordova plugins should usually have two files, a Javascript one and a native one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` outside of onLoad as the first line in your scripts section.