# Form submission in Cordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

[image: CONFIG FILE]I am trying to submit a form in an **Ionic app**.

It's a payment form which takes the user to the payment page on submission.

On iOS devices, it's able to submit and open the page of the payment gateway. However fails to do so in Android.

When I check the logs, two things I notice are **'set native-> JS mode to null'** and Thread specified without a name.

I have tried everything possible. But still no luck.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you set up the cordova-whitelist-plugin and content security policy (CSP) correctly? Especially the CSP in Android.

Comment: @Karthik Could you post your form submission code?

Comment: @Karthink Going by this error trace - 'set native-> js mode to null' i noticed   similar error trace in the following link - https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-code-push/issues/86 If you are using ionic v2, could you please recreate a new project again, port all the contents from old project to the new project and try running once again?

Comment: @Gandhi There is no code that handles the form submission. The submit button on the form submits it.

Comment: @thepio The CSP is set to allow everything.

Comment: @karthik did u tried my suggestion in  second comment

Comment: @Gandhi I am not using ionic2

Comment: @KarthikPriyadarshan Could you atleast recreate a new project, port your code to new project and see if it works?

Comment: Hey try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015471/phonegap-android-native-function-not-getting-called

Comment: What's the Android version?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem here is but, what about using ajax xhr to post data to your php file?

Comment: @KarthikPriyadarshan Can you post cordova config file? Specifically for Android.

Comment: @ErikKralj I added the config file.

Comment: @BurakTokak Can not do it through AJAX. It's a form that submits to payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

> On iOS devices, it's able to submit and open the page of the payment gateway. However fails to do so in Android.

Hey, I had a similar problem with facebook login's javascript API on submit.

Installing Cordova inappbrowser plugin did the trick for me.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

---

Also if this doesn't solve the issue, this is what I would do in your position: (I'm assuming you have a LAMP server)

**1)** Send all your payment data with ajax to a php file to insert the data into your database, then return the id of that inserted line to your javascript and store it on a variable called `insertedPaymentId`.

**2)** Create a php page in your LAMP server lets call it;

http://www.yourdomain.com/paymentSubmit.php

**3)** Then using the in app browser push that insertedPaymentId to that paymentSubmit.php file just after submit button is clicked and the payment data is inserted to database;

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.yourdomain.com/paymentSubmit.php?paymentID='+insertedPaymentId, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

**4)** Take that insertedPaymentId variable in the paymentSubmit.php file with GET and select that payment data from your database on this php page, then using "hidden" inputs, set all the data in this page and have an submit button like "Confirm your payment" like this;

```
<form action="secure.payu/_payment.php...">
<input id="amount" type="hidden" value="<?php $db['amount']; ?>"/>
<input id="productinfo" type="hidden" value="<?php $db['productInfo']; ?>"/>
<input id="firstname" type="hidden" value="<?php $db['firstname']; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Confirm"/>
</form>
```

At this situation what user will see is kind of a popup on their app and asking them to confirm the payment, after that you are actually on a LAMP server and PHP environment, do what you will and if you done with your submission, you can close that window by reading more on inappbrowser.

Hope helps, keep me updated.